# Arm TrustZone on Xilinx zynq zc706, smc #0

Tags: security, xilinx, trustzone, zynq

Arm TrustZone, zynq-zc706

Hi,

I tried enabling TrustZone on Xilinx Zynq zc706 board. After many attempts, still no success.

Does anyone know if I have to enable somehow that option? I downloaded opensource solution for TrustZone implementation (sierraTEE from openvirtualization.org) but I am not able to boot its kernel.

When SMC #0 (during boot) instruction is performed, system goes to PREFETCH ABORT. Do I have to change or do something to enable SMC function (Secure Monitor Call to change worlds).
Please, write whatever you know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the hardware system prior to simply booting the code.  Specifically, there are several clock signals that must be connected in the hardware in order for the NW to function properly.  Xilinx released UG1019 that details a lot of the configuration that must be done.  Once you have the hardware design created properly, you should be able to create a FSBL project, perform the required configuration operations outlined in UG1019, and then boot the SierraTEE.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this project quite useful and have tried this myself on ZedBoard and it work.

https://github.com/tzvisor/ltzvisor